# How to create a path for the argument cwd in subprocess.run

Tags: python, subprocess

I have the following paths:

```
airflow_home = os.path.join("opt", "airflow")
airflow_docs = os.path.join(airflow_home, "docs")
```

And I want `airflow_docs` path to be used within a bash command. For that, I have used the following code:

```
subprocess.run([f"sphinx-apidoc -o ./ ../plugins"],
                       shell=True,
                       cwd=airflow_docs)
```

And I get an error `FileNotFoundError`.

However, this does work:

```
subprocess.run([f"sphinx-apidoc -o ./ ../{doc_module}"],
                       shell=True,
                       cwd="/opt/airflow/docs")
```

So it seems that a missing leading slash is causing the problem. I have searched in google about adding a leading slash to a path with no success. So, is it possible to use `os.path` package for `subprocess.run`, or do I have to use a hardcoded string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a slash, put a slash.

```
airflow_home = os.path.join("/opt", "airflow")
```

But of course, having Python glue together the strings is not really useful. Indeed, the result of `os.path.join` is simply a string, equivalent to a hard-coded string. So just write it out:

```
airflow_home = "/opt/airflow"
```

Or if you want to do this in Python, perhaps prefer `pathlib`:

```
airflow_home = pathlib.Path("/opt") / "airflow"
```

As an aside, your `subprocess` code is broken; you want to pass either a string, with `shell=True`, or a list of tokens, without `shell=True`. (Windows "helpfully" hides this error but it's still wrong.)

```
subprocess.run(
    ["sphinx-apidoc", "-o", "./", "../plugins"],
    cwd=airflow_docs)
```

`subprocess` conveniently allows you to pass in a `pathlib.Path` object as the value of `cwd`, though this might not always have been the case, if you need to support older versions of Python.

You probably want to add `check=True` to have Python raise an error if the subprocess fails. Perhaps see also [Running Bash commands in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538)